# Finding haplogroup through raw DNA data?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, haplogroup

I just got my results from AncestryDNA.

What are some ways to find my haplogroup through my raw DNA data?

Answer (score 9):

I obtained my Y-DNA haplogroup from my AncestryDNA raw DNA file using the first method detailed in this link: 
https://www.geneticgenealogist.net/2016/01/how-to-get-ydna-haplogroup-from.html

In short, it goes through 3 steps:

1/ you convert your AncestryDNA raw DNA file into 23andme format using a small VBS program you can obtain from here:

drive.google.com/file/d/0ByaSZfKQX51lNHJSSUlsNGxTQmM/view

You simply have to put it in the same directory as your unzipped DNA file (txt file), double click, and it will do the conversion and create a new file in the same directory named yourdnafilename_Edited.txt

2/ You install this program and load the 23andme format dna file into it:

drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7vzRsRM2aOQcU5fckNjdEg1ZWs

(it requires .NET Framework 4.0, so you might have to install that first)

Go to File -> Save, and save into another text file

3/ Copy the content of this text file into the text area on this website, and run the predictor:

https://ytree.morleydna.com/

You should get your Y-DNA haplogroup now, which is the result labeled "most likely". If you get BT or F as "most likely" (most people have those, so it's almost redundant), then the next prediction is the most likely (and relevant) for you (there should be more "green" in it than the other options).
If you have a problem or a question, either refer to the article linked above, or ask me. Good luck!

Comment: Chris Morley has simplified things even further. Just load your AncestryDNA(or MyHeritage or 23andMe) raw data file here https://ytree.morleydna.com/extractFromAutosomal and get forwarded to his haplogroup prediction tool.

Comment: I used ytree.morleydna.com with my AncestryDNA raw data file in about 2014 and it worked for me.  Don't know if you still could do it today...  BTW, the link above (https://www.geneticgenealogist.net/2016/01/how-to-get-ydna-haplogroup-from.html) doesn't work for me any longer.)

Comment: @TJinBC The link has been reactivated.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the current normal AncestryDNA product, which tests Autosomal DNA, does not include the Y-DNA or mtDNA SNPs that would be useful for determining your haplogroup(s).

Ancestry previously sold more expensive DNA tests for Y-DNA and mtDNA, but no longer do. FamilyTreeDNA does, however:

https://www.familytreedna.com/

You'll need to download the raw data and figure out the haplogroup yourself using the ISOGG's database:

https://isogg.org/tree/index.html

Comment: AncestryDNA doesn't sell Y-DNA and mtDNA tests. Only FamilyTreeDNA does.

Comment: Please specify what page on the ISOGG website will tell you how to figure out the haplogroup.

Comment: Thanks @lkessler ,I've updated my answer (took me long enough! just noticed your comments).

Answer (score 2):

They call the y chromosome "chromosome 24".

They only test 885 SNP's though.

They also test 17,604 SNP's on the x chromosome (labeled as chromosome 23), plus 440 SNPs labeled as chromosome 25 that are either from chromosome X or from the pseudoautosomal regions of the Y chromosome.

I do not know a tool, as of yet, for filtering these sections out to determine haplogroups but I'm still searching.

http://www.isogg.org/wiki/Autosomal_DNA_testing_comparison_chart

Comment: I've never seen the Y-chromosome called "chromosome 24". That makes no sense because there are 46 chromosomes, in 23 pairs. The first 22 pairs of chromosomes are called the Autosomal chromosomes. The X and Y (pair 23) are called the Sex chromosomes.

Comment: I think it is artifact of AncestryDNA file format. It is the same csv or tabulated file with raw data like ftdna or 23andme provide. And it is very reasonable to write ChrX as Chr23 and ChrY as Chr24 (for example, file generator uses integer type for chromosome number/naming)

Comment: I am totally sure that AncestryDNA designates ChrX as Chr23 because there is such conversion in useful utilities here: http://www.y-str.org/2014/09/autosomal-dna-converter-nix.html

Answer (score 2):

I transferred my Ancestry autosomal test to this site and it gave me my haplo group that matched the Y test I had from National Geographic and FamilyTree:

https://ytree.morleydna.com/extractFromAutosomal

Answer (score 1):

Ancestry tests enough SNPs to get a high level haplogroup. The other answers discussed getting the Y and the Morley method works well BUT women do not have a Y so the only haplogroup they can get is the mtDNA (mitochondrial DNA).

Uploading to Promethease.com which will show health results in your DNA can provide a haplogroup but its not easy to use and I had no luck with it.

Best to test at 23andme to get your high level mtDNA haplogroup or do the detailed mtDNA test at familytreeDNA, likely to be on sale just before mother's day.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the AncestryDNA chip version used to Genotype your DNA, see file header. The [SNPedia Haplogroup](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Haplogroups) site details what’s polled by the different chip versions, and you could spend many an hour manually trailing the ~1,700 Y-DNA SNPs in the file, to call a high level Haplogroup, alternatively you can get the same answer by throwing $0-$12 at [Promethease](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Promethease) (depending on the direction of the wind / whim of the company), which will also return numerous traits, say resistance to plague/aids, lactose toleration, alcohol toleration, eye colour, hair type, ... for the beer tokens.